# How to integrate api with our web service

Tags: php, api, web-services, soap

I have this html code

```
<form action="/domains/login.php">

 </div>

 <div class="container">
 <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

 <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" 
 required>

 <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
 </label>
 </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
 <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
 <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
 </div>
 </form>
```

and also this php code to integrate with api

```
$soapUrl = "http://202.171.47.206:8080/ResellerAPI/ResellerAPIWs?wsdl"; 
$username = 'username'; 
$password = 'password'; 

$client = new SoapClient($soapUrl); 
$result = $client->login(array('username' => $username, 'password' => 
$password))->return; 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result); 

if ((string) $xml->code === '1000') {   
echo "Login successful";
} else {
 echo "Login failed";
throw new Exception("Error:" . $xml->reason . " -- " . $xml->code);

 } 
?>
```

im using this code to integrate then get this error

```
Login failed
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Login failed -- 9999 in 
/home/kognifi6/public_html/domains/login.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} 
thrown in /home/kognifi6/public_html/domains/login.php on line 16
```

Then i hope this will solve because im newbie with this soap api.

Comment: Where does `checkDomainAvailability()` get called in your code?

Comment: im sorry @kerbholz. I have edit it error

Comment: You should use the endpoint URL not WSDL. To get endpoint URL, you can use [SoapUI tool](https://www.soapui.org/) to create new Soap project with your WSDL, then you can get the endpoint by opening any sample request with the generated soap calls

Answer (score -2):

this is error with db connection you can try this. as we as your doi
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406096/6870298

go here

Comment: Whether the API call nor the parsing of the response got anything to do with a db connection. As long as the topic starter does not point out what on line 4 in the checkDomainAvailability.php happens, you can not answer this question with a db connection solution. What makes you think, that this is a db connection issue?